# SQL Server pivot code help needed

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am looking to pivot some data from this query

```
select 
    count(*) as total_customers,
    sum(last_year) as customers_in_last_year
    sum(two_years) as customers_in_last_2_years
from
    Customers
```

which returns this result set:

```
total_customers    customers_in_last_year    customers_in_last_2_years
500                  100                         200
```

What I want to do is flip that to the below, any help?

```
total_customers                500
customers_in_last_year         100
customers_in_last_2_years      200
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #Table11
    ([total_customers] int, [customers_in_last_year] int, [customers_in_last_2_years] int)
;

INSERT INTO #Table11
    ([total_customers], [customers_in_last_year], [customers_in_last_2_years])
VALUES
    (500, 100, 200)


select [subject],total_customerss as  total_customers
from #Table11 s
unpivot
(
  total_customerss  
  for subject in ([total_customers], [customers_in_last_year], [customers_in_last_2_years])
) u;
```

output

```
total_customers               500
customers_in_last_year        100
customers_in_last_2_years     200
```

append your query like this

```
SELECT [subject]
    ,total_customerss AS total_customers
FROM (
    SELECT count(*) AS total_customers
        ,sum(last_year) AS customers_in_last_year, sum(two_years) AS customers_in_last_2_years
    FROM Customers
    ) s
unpivot(total_customerss FOR subject IN (
            [total_customers]
            ,[customers_in_last_year]
            ,[customers_in_last_2_years]
            )) u;
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you store your result into a table called `YourResult` (which can be a temp table, variable table), you could do the following:

```
select 'total_customers' as col, total_customers as val from YourResult
union all
select 'customers_in_last_year' as col, customers_in_last_year as val from YourResult
union all
select 'customers_in_last_2_years' as col, customers_in_last_2_years as val from YourResult
```

Check a working example [here](http://rextester.com/GXVF23785).